# PureScript - how to import just the string join operator "<>"?

Tags: purescript

The following code works:

```
import Prelude
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Console (log)

message1 :: String
message1 = "Hello"

message2 :: String
message2 = "World!"

message3 :: String
message3 = message1 <> " " <> message2

main ∷ Effect Unit
main = do
  log (message3)
```

However, the following line,

```
import prelude
```

Uses the global import syntax, and all of prelude is imported. I would like to import *only* the operators being used (the <>) operator.

I've tried a few things such as

```
import Prelude (<>)
import Prelude (Join)
import Prelude (Data)
```

But they all just throw an error.

How do you import just <>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parenthesise the operator name:

```
import Prelude ( (<>) )
```

Comment: Excellent, worked immediately. Could you share a link to where this is documented for future question visitors?

Comment: I don't think it's documented anywhere. PureScript hasn't hit version 1.0 yet, doesn't have an official spec.

Comment: It's mentioned in passing in https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/language/Modules.md#importing-modules